# Change orientation of DatePicker in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, datepicker, orientation

I am having some UI problems with the DatePicker. Setting dates in my app relies on the day of the week, which the DatePicker lacks without the calendar, so I am using the calendar so the user can see the day of the week. The only problem is, it displays them side to side like this:

[image]

Which makes the calendar appear very cramped, especially because this is on a mobile device, so the numbers are very small. Is there a way to make the orientation change, where the slider is on the top and the calendar is on the bottom? The calendar looks much better when it doesn't have the slider next to it as it is bigger, but I need both the slider and calendar.

Comment: Since you're showing the calendar, is it imperative that you show the spinner as well? You could always setSpinnersShown(false).

Comment: Yes, as it is much more readable, the calendar appears way to small, even when the spinner is disabled.